# Create Recursive Regex.IsMatch Expression<Func<T, bool>> for nested property of different Type

Tags: c#, regex, recursion, lambda

I have a method for creating a `Regex` based `Expression` which works fine for direct properties of the relevant entity. So the below work fine for anything like `entity.property`

```cs
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateRegExExpression<T>(string pattern, string property)
{
        var paramObject = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var paramType = Expression.TypeAs(paramObject, typeof(T));
        var propertyField = Expression.Property(paramType, property);

        var _pattern = Expression.Constant(pattern, typeof(string));
        var paramsEx = new Expression[] { propertyField, _pattern };

        var methodInfo = typeof(Regex).GetMethod("IsMatch", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });
        if (!methodInfo.IsStatic || methodInfo == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        
        var lamdaBody = Expression.Call(null, methodInfo, paramsEx);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(lamdaBody, paramObject);
}
```

However, I have not been able to make this work for a nested property, such as `entity.sub_entity.property` as the call to `CreateRegExExpression` requires the `<T>` class to appropriately return the lamba?

Has anyone got any tips on how to construct the lambda for a nested property dynamically as the below works fine, but I can't seem to work out how to make that recursive using the above function.

```cs
Expression<Func<entity, bool>> lambda = e => Regex.Ismatch(e.sub_entity.property, pattern)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you can allow passing the "path" instead of just property name and then split and iterate it:

```
static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateRegExExpression<T>(string pattern, string property)
{
    var paramObject = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var paramType = Expression.TypeAs(paramObject, typeof(T));
    var props = property.Split(".");
    Expression propertyField = Expression.Property(paramType, props[0]);

    foreach (var prop in props.Skip(1))
    {
        propertyField = Expression.Property(propertyField, prop);
    }

    var _pattern = Expression.Constant(pattern, typeof(string));
    var paramsEx = new Expression[] { propertyField, _pattern };

    var methodInfo = typeof(Regex).GetMethod("IsMatch", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });
    if (!methodInfo.IsStatic || methodInfo == null)
        throw new NotSupportedException();
        
    var lamdaBody = Expression.Call(null, methodInfo, paramsEx);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(lamdaBody, paramObject);
}
```

With usage like `CreateRegExExpression(pattern, "sub_entity.property")`

Alternatively if you don't have full path, only "previous" property expression you can use reflection to invoke the method:

```
var memberReflectedType = previousPropertyField.Member.ReflectedType;
var propFieldType = previousPropertyField.Type;
var makeGenericMethod = typeof(CreateRegExExpressionHolder).GetMethod(nameof(CreateRegExExpression), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .MakeGenericMethod(propFieldType);
var invoke = makeGenericMethod.Invoke(null, new[] { pattern, finalPropName }) as Expression;
```

Comment: How ludicrously simple :-) Thanks! That works a charm!
I hadn't realized you could simply traverse the path...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Guru's answer.

You can always take a look at how the C# compiler infers it for your code
`Expression<Func<entity, bool>> lambda = e => Regex.IsMatch(e.sub_entity.property, pattern)` on [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwHQBkCWAdgI7YCiAHgA4BOApgM4P4D2hDA3MmpjgCp0KAF2wAlOgHMArgBsAhjUq1GzNp2TcAzJhjoAwugDeydKfQmzUbVAAs6ALIAKAJRGz780gsePANwXoVHJCQnQ0hOgAvOgARHAwmjFcSD4+SvRMrIQAPFAArNl0hEL4QgCeADToAEYsLDIAfA3o8gC21cByUeh0Uc3iEoLYAJIM9sEAxgAWjnTYDFLVAPpFJeXYtCxUYeVVQSFhhM7J7gC+yOdeKLqrpWXIximY2gvVZMV36K8rH+VGg0IOF86IDLpduLpXu81vckI9TFZeBhNtsaH9DACgQwQRwwUA) or LinqPad:

[image]